# .htaccess to redirect all URL to SSL excpet the one with "s" QueryString

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a WordPress powered website and I am using following `.htaccess` code to redirect all URLs from HTTP to HTTPS

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Well, it is working fine! But now I need to redirect only one page with QueryString `'s'` to the non SSL (HTTP) one.
The structure of the URL is-

http**s**://www.example.com/articles/?s={random_texts} **(current)**

and I want it to redirect to -

http://www.example.com/articles/?s={random_texts} **(looking for)**

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [starkeen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3160747/starkeen) after a little modification I figured out the problem. Here is the code which resolved the query-

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/articles/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !s [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /articles/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} s [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/articles/\?s=.+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
##redirect /articles/\?s=.+ from https to http##
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /articles/\?s=.+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Clear your browser's cache before testing this.

Comment: What url are you going to?

Comment: Thanks @anubhava sir!